# Android which layout to use

Tags: android, android-layout

I have some trouble creating something like this with android.

I add image buttons in a `tableLayout` but things get messed. 
Should i use `linearLayout` instead? The problem is that they should stretch probably to fit...

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming each bill/coin is a separate element you can do this in 3 linear layouts, which are all children of a parent linear layout

pseudo...

```
<linearLayout
   vertical>
     <!-- first row -->
     <linearLayout 
        horizontal
        weightSum = 2>
         <image layout_width="0dp" layout_weight="1">
         <image layout_width="0dp" layout_weight="1">
     </linearLayout>  
     <!-- second row -->
     <linearLayout 
        horizontal
        weightSum = 2>
         <image layout_width="0dp" layout_weight="1">
         <image layout_width="0dp" layout_weight="1">
     </linearLayout>  

     <!-- coins -->
     <linearLayout 
        horizontal
        weightSum = 3>
         <image layout_width="0dp" layout_weight="1">
         <image layout_width="0dp" layout_weight="1">
         <image layout_width="0dp" layout_weight="1">
     </linearLayout>
</linearLayout>
```

I'm leaving out all the android specific stuff that you will have to fill in, and just providing the essentials.  I believe this will get you what you're after.

You'll need to add some marginLeft and marginRight on the middle coin to push them apart so that they aren't sitting side by side (or just add that padding in the image itself as transparency).

Comment: thank you a lot. I had this on my mind but guys are against linearlayouts generally. But i doupt if it can be done easier. I use imageButton not images . I am not sure if clickable images have visual effect when clicked.. It seems that it works without gravity= center_horizontal

Comment: it doesn't matter what your views are (Images, ImageButtons, Buttons, etc.) Android treats them all the same. You're right... center_horizontal is superfluous here... I will remove it from my explanation.  There's no reason to be "against" linearLayouts. They're a tool. Use them when they are appropriate for a given problem (like this one).

Answer (score 1):

I can highly recommend the use of `LinearLayout`, using it you can use `layout_weight` on it's child elements to make the width/heights of elements equal.

In this case I would use one LinearLayout with orientation:vertical, with height set to `wrap_content` and inside it use three LinearLayouts with orientation:horizontal with width match_parent and height wrap_content.

Inside each of the three LinearLayouts you set your ImageViews and specify width: 0dp, height: wrap_content and layout_weight: 1.